Persistent "Loading..." indicator in Outlook add-in task pane
For some accounts, even the simplest add-ins (including for example Microsoft's Hello World add-in) have this behaviour on Outlook for Windows Classic: when opening the task pane, a "Loading..." text and a spinner are shown, and either the add-in never loads or, if it loads (sometimes it does immediately, others after a long while), that "Loading..." text stays behind it.
On other accounts, this never happens.
Has anyone ever encountered this issue and found a solution for it?
Environment:

Outlook for Windows Classic, version 2402 (Build 17328.20184 Click-to-run)
Microsoft 365 Business Standard license
Add-in installed via sideload on Outlook for Web

